# Lodash - find value in nested Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have an object structure like as mentioned below in link

https://jsonblob.com/3511b867-dd4b-11e9-85e4-63b804994c26

I want to search say `firstname: Dianca` in all the nodes under `persons` using lodash.

I do not want to harcode the node names as that way i have mention a lot of nodes to look for. I need to search it dynamically under `person` node no matter where it is located under Object structure.

I have tried a way like as below but in vain(like harcoded stuff)

```
_.filter(users, o => 
  _.some(o.Positions, ['persons.firstname', 'Dianca'])
)
```

and secondly, i want to get all names under `persons` node and save it to new array..

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What a Question !! It took me an year to build a logic for you :)

```
function findUser(data, firstName) {

    var object;
    data.some(function f(a) {
        if (a.firstname == firstName) {
            object = a;
            return true;
        }

        _.each(Object.keys(a), function (value, key) {
            // loops through json objects in waypath
            if (!_.isEmpty(object)) {
                return false; // stop once we get the user
            }
            if (isNaN(value)) {
                // only data with string keys need to iterate more
                // when there is an array with elements
                if (Array.isArray(a[value]) && a[value].length != 0) {
                    a[value].some(f); // recursion (Didn't use return because we are in loop)
                } else if (!_.isEmpty(a[value])) {
                    // when there is an object within object
                    _.each(Object.keys(a[value]), function (val, key2) {
                        if (Array.isArray(a[value][val]) && a[value][val].length != 0) {
                            a[value][val].some(f); // recursion
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });

    return object;
}

console.log(findUser(data, "Phyllis"));
```

Should be exactly what you need. Enjoy !!

Comment: and in another year, i have created one :) i shall try this as well

Comment: sure, do share the best solution and mark as an answer .